# Selecionar coluna com valor *** do Excel

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-excel, select, datatable, importação

Bom dia amigos!

Preciso de uma ajuda.

Estou fazendo um "Select" de uma planilha de Excel em VB.Net para importar os dados no banco porém uma coluna não está trazendo os dados corretamente. Esta coluna possui tanto números quanto *'s; quando são números ele traz os valores, porém quando são *'s (*, **, ***, ****) traz {}, gostaria que toda a coluna retornasse como String. É possível?

--Método que importa a planilha

```
Dim dtbSheet As New DataTable
    Dim wrkConnectionString As String = String.Format(CONNECTION_STRING_OLEDB_EXCEL, pPathFile)
    Dim wrkSQL As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", pSheet)

    'Intancia conexão
    Dim wrkConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim wrkCmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim wrkDa As OleDbDataAdapter = Nothing

    Try
        wrkConnection = New OleDbConnection(wrkConnectionString)
        wrkCmd = New OleDbCommand(wrkSQL, wrkConnection)
        wrkDa = New OleDbDataAdapter(wrkCmd)
        wrkDa.Fill(dtbSheet)
    Finally
        If wrkConnection IsNot Nothing AndAlso wrkConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then wrkConnection.Close()
    End Try

    Return dtbSheet
```

--Exemplo da coluna

[image: Exemplo da coluna]

Answer (score -1):

Como está selecionando dados de uma planilha, uma solução simples é tratar estes dados antes desta seleção, o que pode ser feito pelo **VB.Net**, por meio de uma **macro** do **Excel** ou pelo **VBA** (menos indicado neste caso, já que está usando o **VB.Net**).

Supondo que a **Planilha1** contém seus dados e que a **Planulha2** servirá de apoio para este **tratamento aos dados**, o objetivo é pegar os dados da primeira planilha como estão e colar na segunda em formato de texto.

O código abaixo refere-se ao código em **VBA** ou de uma **macro** do **Excel**, o que pode ser adaptado para o teu caso, ou dependendo do uso que faz da planilha, esta **macro** poderia ser acionada "sempre" antes do teu sistema pegar estes dados.

**Segue o código:**

```
Private Sub CopiarColarEspecial()

Sheets("Planilha1").Select

Range("A1:A90").Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("Planilha2").Select

Range("A1").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```